# Wordpress Loop not aligned to the left

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

My wordpress Loop (Abfrage-Loop in german) is not aligned to the left on the website, even though it is in the editor and I do not understand why.

Please help.

[not aligned on site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9TMyl.jpg)
[but aligned in editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cFrVe.png)

I do not know how to fix this, as this doesnt make sense to me.